# Is there a way to just highlight with no comments in Acrobat Pro XI?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, highlighting

I have Acrobat Pro XI and I want to simply highlight text in a PDF to share with someone else. When I use the highlighter tool, it automatically creates a comment, which is simply the highlight text. That makes reading the doc very confusing for someone else. I just want "dumb" highlighting as one might do in Word. Any suggestions?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Edit - Preferences - Commenting - "Automatically open comment
pop-ups for comments other than notes" and "Copy selected text..." checkboxes will fix this. Or use Acrobat Reader!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Foxit Reader for highlighting, it's one of the easiest tools to do the highlighting